# What to use for Shell Access?

Tags: shell, remote-access

I just purchased a virtual dedicated server-plan that comes with shell access. It's been a while since I've actually used shell access remotely, so I'm a bit behind the times. Years ago I used [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), but I'm curious if there are any better options that I should consider for establishing that connection, and managing my server remotely.

I figured this question would be most appropriately asked here since it is regarding tools.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). It definitely does the job for me.

Comment: @Josh: Thanks for the link. The reason I didn't include it is that the OP already did in the question.

Answer (score 3):

I also use putty its solid. I have tried other tools but tons of other software tools integrate with putty but its never as smooth as you hope.

The more I use unix/linux tools I want a system the integrates better with these systems.

Answer (score 2):

I use Secure Shell Client. Works for me. Also includes a SFTP tool. From [SSH Corp](http://www.ssh.com/), now Tectia Corp.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Tunnelier for most of the work I do, because it can save passwords with the profiles and has SFTP functionality  too. It doesn't have many features of Putty though.

Another good option is [Putty Tray](http://haanstra.eu/putty/) which is basically Putty with some more features.

> PuTTY Tray is an improved version of
>   PuTTY (Win32). It features some
>   cosmetic changes, and a number of
>   addons to make it more useful and much
>   more fun to use.
>
> **Features:**
>
> New default icon
>
> Minimizing to the system tray (on CTRL
>   + minimize, always or directly on startup)
>
> (Tray) icon customizable
>
> Blinks tray icon when a bell signal is
>   received
>
> Configurable window transparency
>
> URL hyperlinking
>
> Portability: optionally stores session
>   configuration in files (for example:
>   on a USB drive) like portaPuTTY
>
> Easy access to the 'always on top'
>   setting (in the system menu)
>
> Reconnects when your PC wakes up from
>   stand-by
>
> Attempts to reconnect when the
>   connection fails